# render video with GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am trying to apply filter(like the filters of Instagram) to an existing video.

I used GLSurfaceView to show the video frames and hope to render each frame with onDrawFrame() by applying a certain filter to the incoming frame.

But inside onDrawFrame() how could I get the incoming frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want your filters to work.

If you'd like to have OpenGL ES modify the pixels, you can do filters with fragment shaders [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg).

If you just want to overlay a static image on top of the video frame, you can play the frames into a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) and then render the frame blended with a bitmap (again with GLES).

[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) has various examples; the "texture from Camera" activity is probably a good starting point.  Other activities in Grafika demonstrate recording GLES rendering with MediaCodec if you want to save the output (though on Android 5.x you can use MediaRecorder instead).

FWIW, I would recommend using a plain SurfaceView, rather than a GLSurfaceView, as the EGL management can get a bit painful.

Comment: thanks. I am going to change the pixels of the coming frames. I will have a look at what you pointed out. As for the GLSurfaceView I heard it provides easier ways to use OpenGL ES but SurfaceView is harder to use. Is that true?

Comment: GLSurfaceView is a wrapper for SurfaceView. It handles the EGL setup and manages a renderer thread. For a simple GLES app it's nice to have these things done for you, but if you're manipulating the images and recording them it can sometimes get in the way.